# Where are stored cache, temporary files and all data in Brave Browser?

Tags: 18.04, browser, cache

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 and Brave downloaded and installed as a snap.

I suspect that in spite of I have set Brave configuration to erase cookies and history, etc, information is been held up in some way.

But I can't find either cache or temporary files originated when I am using Brave Browser.

Can someone help me to find where are stored cache, temporary files and all data in Brave Browser?

If someone could tell me how can I be sure that Brave browser delete all data when I close it, personal configuration I had set up, I would be pleased to accept the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

On my Ubuntu, `brave-browser` cache is stored in :

`$HOME/.cache/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/`

and the `brave-browser` data is stored in :

`$HOME/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/`

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Brave as a snap on 18.04, you will find it in Home snap  brave.

Answer (score 0):

**Cache Location and Clearing for Brave**
(with Brave installed as a snap from Snap Store)

Location is `~/snap/brave/common/.cache/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/Cache/Cache_Data`

Locate it via the Terminal command line:

```
cd $HOME
cd snap/brave/common/.cache/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/Cache/Cache_Data
```

I use a Chrome store extension to easily clear cache in Brave (tested in Linux Mint 20):

Clean All - History & Cache Cleaner Version 1.0.15

My version of Brave installed on Linux Mint 20:

- Version 1.36.109 Chromium: 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (64-bit)

My version of Linux Mint:

- Description:  Linux Mint 20
- Release:  20
- Codename: ulyana